# replace text only in clause determinated by keywork

Tags: sed

I want to processes text in some files that sometime expression exist in one line and sometime in multiple line

for example in multiple line

```
myfunc(param1,
param2,
param3);
```

or in one line

```
myfunc(param1, param2, param3);
```

does exist way that sed processes text only between `myfunc` and `;`? keywords

at first step this help to me to port all multiple line to a line. Then I can to do my manupulation one a line type

if this possible?

Comment: Edit your question to show the expected output given that sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything even slightly more interesting you should be using awk. Something like this is probably what you want:

```
$ cat file
myfunc(param1,
param2,
param3);

myfunc(param1, param2, param3);

$ cat tst.awk
/myfunc/ { buf=""; inBlock=1 }
inBlock {
    buf = (buf==""?"":buf RS) $0
    if (/;/) {
        $0 = buf
        sub(/param2/,"lets have a tea party")
        inBlock = 0
    }
}
!inBlock

$ awk -f tst.awk file
myfunc(param1,
lets have a tea party,
param3);

myfunc(param1, lets have a tea party, param3);
```

Just replace the `sub(/param2/,"lets have a tea party")` line with whatever it is you really want to do with that block of text between `myfunc` and `;`.

Comment: thanks but if I have several time the key what i need to do? for example replace all appearance of param2 that can be more than once?

Comment: As I said 3 days ago - edit your question to show sample input and expected output. Make it concise, precise, and testable. You may want to start over with a new question as I doubt if anyone's going to go back and re-read this one after you change it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `sed` script:

*extract.sed:*

```
# Check for "my"
/\bmy\b/    {   
    # Replace everything in front of
    # my (including it)
    s/.*\bmy\b//
    # Define a label "a"
    :a  
    # If the line does not contain "processes"
    /\bprocesses\b/!{
        # Get the next line of input and append
        # it to the pattern buffer
        N   
        # Branch back to label "a"
        ba  
    }   
    # Replace "processes" and everything after it
    s/\bprocesses\b.*//
    # Print the pattern buffer
    p   
}
```

Call it like this:

```
sed -nf extract.sed input.txt
```

Comment: thanks but I need between my-processes # Replace "processes" and everything 'after it' must be 'before it' no? I want inside the clause.

Comment: It works, meaning it outputs `expression to`. Have you tried it?

Comment: ops!! sorry this do that ,but my purpose was to replace some text between `my` and `processes` include.

Comment: Then simply replace `s/\bprocesses\b//` by `s/\bprocesses\b/TEXT YOU WANT TO INSERT processes/`

Comment: no I didn't successes to do that. I update my quesion maybe this can help

Comment: Have you at least tried to make my solution working for you? It is indeed what you want, you simply need to adapt it. Just telling "It doesn't work" is not enough!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87168/discussion-between-herzl-shemuelian-and-hek2mgl).